# enable_profile_selector with FB javascript SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Regarding this information: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish

Parameters: target_id and uid description says:

If I want to publish as page, I should use the 'enable_profile_selector' option with FB.login. This option enables the profile selector on the permission dialog. as I understood enable_profile_selector it's not permission but send it as GET parameter, then when user is asked permissions he can choose profile, if I am a facebook page admin then I can choose page page profile.

So basically problem is where to enable 'enable_profile_selector' and how pass "enable_profile_selector" parameter with javascript sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here anyway I wanted to get the page access token.So I used this method 
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/